# Over accessing a content provider in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to write an app that loads in a load of words from a content provider. Then i want to update certain fields associated with a word, ie view count etc, one at a time

What is the best approach to accessing the data.
So first i load all the words into a Cursor object, when i want to update a word view-count do i just call an update event . Will this update just the Content provider or will it also update the fetched results that are stored in the Cursor

After a word is viewed i want to remove it from the Cursor object so it wont be shown again, is that possible  or do i need to do a full query to get all the words again

sorry if vague or hard to understand

Comment: How do you want to show those words, in a `ListView`?

Comment: At the moment they wont be shown, just stored in the background and used one at a time